# Too little space on a rented Windows Server 2008 virtual machine. How can I free space?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, cleanup

I rented a VPS / virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 with 16 GB of HDD.

The Windows install was fresh so I went on to install the automatic updates, patches etc. I soon found out that I now have 200 MB free as SP2 couldn't install reporting free space too low.

I've uninstalled all features and roles and every program and I am now at 400 MB free.

How can I go about finding out WHO is occupying my space and HOW / IF I can fix this?

Thanks :(

---

Later Edit 1 :  Initially the hoster put up a Windows 2008 **R2** VPS image which had MUCH more available space (I think 7 GB of the same 16 GB)... could it be that **R2** uses much less space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any specific advice, but if you want to see where the space has gone, try [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info). It's the best tool I know of to visualize disk space.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it so I won't have to gather my statistics manually.

Comment: Turns out this abysmal piece of crap of WebPI (Web Platform Installer) that I was forced into using to install SQL Server Express was eating like 1GB.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're largely boned.  We don't sell Windows 2008 VPSes with less than 20GB of space, since our base images (really, really base -- nothing in them we can easily remove) consume about 14GB of space before putting anything useful on the machine.

Comment: Well.. I can always upgrade to the next plan which is only 50% more money but one more core, 512MB more RAM and 16GB more HDD. However it seems like selling a car with 1/4 gallon tank. Nothing to do except buy-back..

Comment: +1 for "largely boned".  A 2008 box with 16GB is near useless...

Comment: @Andrei: Yeah, I'd be a bit suspicious of a company that was willing to sell you a Win2k8 server with so little disk, but you have to take that with a grain of salt because I work in that business myself.  Certainly I'd be asking them their opinion on the subject, though, to see what they have to say.

Comment: I am really sorry I went to accept SomeName's answer but in a practical way it was the most useful. HOWEVER your answer is the eye opener and gives me strength to better negotiate my terms with the hoster. I wish I could have chosen yours too..

Comment: Well, you can always go and upvote two of my other answers at random or something... <grin>

Comment: It has been done :)

Comment: +1 16GB is nowhere near enough for 2k8, we require our clients to get at least 35GB for C: now I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you see any "Uninstall" directories in C:\Windows I'd say you could safely remove them and free up 100megs more or so...

Comment: I'll be doing a thorough analysis of the largest folders and their subfolders to see where the lump is. For now C:\WINDOWS occupies like 95%

Comment: @djangofan: if you're referring to all the $NtUninstallxxx$ compressed folders that you're used to seeing in Server 2003, those don't exist any more as of Vista/2008. I think they may have been absorbed into the very confusing winsxs folder.